# SDKs seem missing in Azure hosted web service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following pipe. I've tested it with the two lines active as well - same result. For some reason, the pipe works well and the application seems to be deployed. However, I get application error and the logs suggest that I have no SDKs to pick from. The application plan is set to Linux and that's the type of my host for the service.

```
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my-serv-con'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    appName: 'app-name'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    # runtimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|7.0'
    # startUpCommand: 'dotnet run'
```

In the [guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-azure-pipelines?tabs=yaml#deploy-a-net-app) there's no mentioning explicit installation. Answers like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1182971/azure-devops-release-of-asp-net-core-api-to-app-se) indicate that my pipe should work.

What can I be missing?

I added an extra step right before this to actually check the version of the .NET Core and, apparently, there is one, as shown below.

> Generating script.
> Script contents:
> dotnet --version
> =================== Starting Command Output ====================
> /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/09b37939-9090-4ba8-b662-83e0fa677bea.sh
> 7.0.302
> Finishing: Verify .NET Core version

I also tried the below as suggested by [a noob guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net70&pivots=development-environment-cli#2-publish-your-web-app).

```
az webapp up --sku F1 --name app-name --os-type linux
```

Still, the same result, despite the log stating otherwise.

```
{
  "URL": "http://...",
  "appserviceplan": "asp-aux-linux",
  "location": "swedencentral",
  "name": "app-name",
  "os": "Linux",
  "resourcegroup": "res-group",
  "runtime_version": "dotnetcore|7.0",
  "runtime_version_detected": "7.0",
  "sku": "BASIC",
  "src_path": "C:\\source\\dev\\..."
}
```

The error message from the logs tells me the following.

> [INFO]  Now listening on: http://[::]:8081
> [INFO]     _____
> [INFO]    /  _  \ __________ _________   ____
> [INFO]   /  /*\  \*__   /  |  _  __ _/ __ \
> [INFO]  /    |    /    /|  |  /|  | /\  ***/
>
> [INFO]  _***|__  /_____ __**/ |**|    ___  >
> [INFO]          /      /                  /
> [INFO]  A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
> [INFO]
> [INFO]  Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
> [INFO]  Dotnet quickstart: https://aka.ms/dotnet-qs
> [INFO]  ASP .NETCore Version: 7.0.5
> [INFO]  Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
> [INFO]  Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
> [INFO]  Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
> [INFO]  Running oryx create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -defaultAppFilePath /defaulthome/hostingstart/hostingstart.dll     -bindPort 8080 -bindPort2 '' -userStartupCommand 'dotnet run'
> [INFO]  Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
> [INFO]  Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
> [INFO]  Build Operation ID: 282269c7-21c0-4477-a682-d0865756e8ad
> [INFO]
> [INFO]  Agent extension
> [INFO]  Before if loop >> DotNet Runtime
> [INFO]  DotNet Runtime 7.0Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
> [INFO]  Running user provided startup command...
> [ERROR]  The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
> [ERROR]    * You intended to execute a .NET application:
> [ERROR]        The application 'run' does not exist.
> [ERROR]    * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
> [ERROR]        No .NET SDKs were found.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR]  Download a .NET SDK:
> [ERROR]  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR]  Learn about SDK resolution:
> [ERROR]  https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found

Comment: Can you please post the runtime error you're seeing?

Comment: @simon-pearson Here ya go.

Comment: you may have to share the part of your application code which prints `Before if loop`. Are you trying to run `dotnet run` from within your application?

Comment: Not that this is an enduring fix but if you target .NET 6 does the problem go away?

Comment: @simon-pearson Nope. It seems like **no** .NET SDKs are there at all. Very weird...

Comment: @simon-pearson This was very weird. I redid the setup by creating the service in the portal using the web client instead of wiring it up with Azure CLI and the pipeline worked. So the pipeline as such is correct. But now the weird part: when I removed the web service and recreated it using my Azure CLI script, the pipeline kept working. I can't explain it. However, another newly created resource group behaved the same way! I guess our security guys do something fishy when they create the groups for us. God knows what and, at this stage, I don't have the energy to fight with them...   :)